# How to add custom parameter to Doctrine Column type

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to make a custom column type, but the SQL need to depend on a custom parameter.
Default types handle those parameters without issues eg. string type has length.
How can I add one for my type.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
class EnumType extends Type
{
    const ENUM = 'enum';

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return self::ENUM;
    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        $class = $fieldDeclaration['class'];

        if (!is_subclass_of($class, Enum::class)) {
            throw new \Exception('You must specify a valid enum class');
        }

        $values = call_user_func([$class, 'getValues']);

        return "ENUM('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')";
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?Point
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?string
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So far I tried:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="enum", class="App\Enums\OrderStatus")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="enum", options={"class":"App\Enums\OrderStatus"})
     */
    protected $status;
```

First one did not work at all showing an error that class field is not defined.
Second one did work fine, but then it always tried to remake the column since it was not detecting `class` when loading definition from database.

Comment: do you have so many enum'able classes, that you can't afford one doctrine type for each of those? then the types would be distinct/unique, the classes could be baked in. but I get the pain, symfony's (or doctrine orm?) integration falls a bit short on custom types ...

Comment: I have quite a few, since the project I am working on is quite large.
The issue is I don't want to define a new type every time I add a field to database. It will get hard to keep track very fast, since project I am working on is a modular CMS split across multiple bundles. Also Enum is just an example, I have a few other configurable database types eg. Point with 2 different SRID values.

Comment: as far as I can tell, the `class` attribute/option is not stored in the database comment for that column (specifically, because `options` is for platform). So, whatever is read from the database can never be equal to what you have. Essentially it all comes down to how symfony/doctrine converts the annotations into types. I believe you would have to modify that process to inject your very variable types into doctrine's type system. I was at the same position as you were once. Luckily there were only a few "enum" types and splitting them into distinct doctrine types did the job wonderfully.

Comment: maybe you could create your own Annotation, which would then generate the doctrine types, register them, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget configure types in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` ?

It must look like:

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
      types:
         enum: 'App\Doctrine\Types\EnumType' #Change it to valid class
```

and in connection section add a mapping_types:

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
      connections:
         default:
            mapping_types:
               enum: enum
```

Comment: I did register my type, yes.